# Buy a second seat in order to bring an extra bag?

Tags: luggage, international-travel, easyjet

We're trying to get from Krakow to London in order to fly home on Virgin this summer. AFAIK all the intra-Europe flights share the same luggage policy: 20-25kg max luggage weight *per passenger*, with a overweight charge of 5-12 euros *per kilo* and no option for a second bag.  We'd like to bring an extra suitcase of personal effects.

Lacking any other reasonable options, I had the bright idea of flying EasyJet to London and just buying an extra $122 ticket so we could bring one more suitcase.  But I'm not sure if that's even possible, and not sure if EasyJet is still going to hold me to the 20 kilos *per person*.

Would this strategy work?

***Update***

What we ended up doing was flying first from Krakow to Frankfurt on Lufthansa, and then buying a completely separate ticket from Frankfurt to London (not even on the same itinerary). KraKow isn't big enough to have a lot of *international* options, and going to London leaves the Schengen zone.  Trying to get directly from Krakow to London had too few choices.  And Lufthansa has a reasonable baggage policy.

Comment: You can take two bags in Raynair. In wizzair you can buy an extra place and take a fragile stuff like a music instrument on board.

Comment: Mithy: Neither of those airlines flies out of Cracow. And for EasyJet: "Each passenger who pays for a hold bag can take up to 20kg of luggage. This weight allowance applies to the passenger rather than to the bag so purchasing extra bags is possible but will not increase the weight allowance." http://www.easyjet.com/en/planning/baggage.html

Comment: Easyjet has quite a particular policy. If you add one bag to your reservation, you are allowed to take one piece of luggage with a maximum weight of up to 20 kilograms. If you want to take more, everything has to be paid separately. Just adding an second bag does not automatically entitle you to take more than 20 kilograms of luggage. Suppose you would like to take two bags of 18kg each. Then yo will have to pay a fee to take a second bag. In addition, you will have to pay a fee for the additional weight (+16kg).

Comment: Would it make sense to just pay the ticket for someone under the condition he/she can't bring luggage?

Comment: I edited my answer below to answer your question (which I didn't see at first). In short, yes you could do that, but there's a bunch of potential problems you're opening yourself up to.

Answer (score 5):

I know you've solved this -- last year from the dates, but just in case it comes up again, as I understand you can't buy a separate seat because you'll have nobody to check in for that seat. All baggage needs to have a named passenger and you don't have a passenger to check in.

However, at least a few weeks ago, EasyJet allowed you to check an extra bag (for a few) but the 20k limit applies to all the bags (but you can buy more for a fee). 6k and 1 bag extra cost me 30GBP booked in advance.

If you're travelling with a lot of luggage you're better to look at shipping it somehow, or check out the difference in business class flights on a non-budget airline. They have a bigger baggage allowance and, if you get a good deal, it can actually work out cheaper (even better if you have status with an affiliated frequent flyer scheme).

But you'll never be able to send baggage checked into an empty seat. Even if someone went to the airport with you and checked in the bagged would (probably) be offloaded when it was clear they weren't going to board the plane.

**Edit to answer Andra's question**

If you can arrange with someone *you trust* to pay their ticket and have them carry your baggage then that would work. However they're going to be asked 'did you pack this yourself' -- if I was doing that I would definitely want to go through the bag. No way am I checking a random bag onto a plane. Even for a friend. But, in theory, you can do that -- just be aware that people are going to regard it as somewhere between strange and outright illegal and that may get you into issues.

Also, if they happen to lose that bag you'll need the support of the extra person to get it returned (and they'll likely have to identify the bag and contents to prove it's theirs).

Seriously, shipping stuff is not that expensive -- particularly if you don't care how long it takes to get there.

Answer (score 2):

On one airport I saw an advertisement of a company that seems to specialize in [shipping excess baggage](http://www.excess-baggage.com/). It might be more convenient to use these guys. Disclaimer: I am not affiliated and I have never tried this company.

Also for the particular route from Poland to London you have a choice of local companies that specialize in road transport and cater for Polish emigrants in the UK, e.g. [I successfully used this one](http://eagletransport.net.pl/)